# How to send Push notifications using Intel XDK?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intel-xdk

I developed a simple android app using Intel XDK with basic skills of HTML, CSS & JS. When comes to integrate push notifications, Which is better GCM or any messaging service ??

Also, how to register the client app with GCM & know the registration-id?? Ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many push notification services out there that can be used in Intel XDK to implement push notification using their Cordova plugin.

here are a few, all work with IntelXDK:

**Pushwoosh** - http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

**Parse** - https://www.parse.com/questions/push-notification-with-phonegap-plugin-using-javascript

**Urban Airship** - http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/phonegap.html

**Phonegap push plugin** - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push